# Why are my settings in user-dirs.conf not taking affect?

Tags: home, xdg-user-dirs

I want the XDG specification folders in my home directory to be lowercase. I've created a file `~/.config/user-dirs.conf` and updated it as such:

```
enabled=True
filename_encoding=UTF-8

DESKTOP=desktop2
DOWNLOAD=downloads2
TEMPLATES=templates2
PUBLICSHARE=public2
DOCUMENTS=documents2
MUSIC=music2
PICTURES=pictures2
VIDEOS=videos2
```

I did a full reboot and logged back into my desktop environment (Xfce) and the folders in my home directory are unchanged.

I am observing the directory tree on the left side of Thunar and Caja to determine if a change has taken affect. I've also placed a file in the `~/Desktop` folder which should disappear when `~/desktop2` is used instead.

According to `man user-dirs.conf`:

> Users can have their own ~/.config/user-dirs.conf file, which
>   overrides the system-wide configuration.

These values are written to `user-dirs.dirs`, as it says within:

> This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update

Comment: You're looking at the `user-dirs.dirs` file. See `man user-dirs.conf`.

Comment: Ah... OK my bad